# Show names on a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I need to load all the names of the playlists on the `thirdviewcontroller` with a table view but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to show a table view on the third view controller with all the names of the playlists that have been created (I create an array with elements of the class playlist, created by myself). On the view did load func I have created two playlists but when I try the app the names don´t show up on the table view.

I have tried to rewrite the code, link the table view again and create the view again, but it does not work. It also does not show any type of failure or closes the app unexpectedly.

I'm new to Swift so I do not know if I'll be doing something more wrong.

**Here is the project (develop branch):** [tree/develop](https://github.com/mamechapa2/musicplayer/tree/develop)

```
//
//  ThirdViewController.swift
//  reproductor
//
//  Created by Macosx on 24/4/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 mamechapa. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation


var favorites:[String] = []
var Playlists:[Playlist] = []

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView2: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(Playlists.count)
        return Playlists.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = Playlists[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("viewdidload")
        super.viewDidLoad()

        crear()

        myTableView2.reloadData()
        print(Playlists[1].name)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func crear(){

        let pl1 = Playlist(name: "Prueba")

        pl1?.addSong(song: songs[0])
        Playlists.append(pl1!)
        print(Playlists[0].name)
        print(Playlists[0].songs[0])

        let pl2 = Playlist(name: "Prueba2")

        pl2?.addSong(song: songs[1])
        Playlists.append(pl2!)
        print(Playlists[1].name)
        print(Playlists[1].songs[0])
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your data is your dataSource, and what to show is your delegate. You have to set your datasource and delegate. You have to set tableView dataSource and Delegate

```
myTableView2.delegate = self
myTableView2.dataSource = self
```

What is [delegate](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/)

[UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

[UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)

Answer (score 0):

Set Delegate and DataSource to myTableView2 So add below two lines in viewDidLoad function and than reload myTableView2.

```
myTableView2.delegate = self
myTableView2.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `UITableViews’s` delegate and data source equal to self.

```
myTableView2.delegate = self;
myTableView2.dataSource = self;
```

Do this in `viewDidLoad()` after `super.viewDidLoad().`

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded your code from the given github location.

It works fine at my end. Below is the image:

[image]

**BTW nice songs!!!**